# Creating the view as PDF in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My requirement is after user taps createPDF button,to generate current view as PDF. Using

**console.log(this.getMain().getActiveItem().renderElement.dom.innerHTML);**

i can able to get entire HTML element. Now i stuck to generate my view as PDF. Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should google pdf viewer.

For example, if you wanted to view the PDF at the URL http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf ,

you would use the URL: http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf

then use HTML object tag and pass the url to "data" attribute. Attached this as html in your view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options if you are working in a browser, (if you are working in mobile devices you should working with inAppBrowser cordova plugin)

1º With the mozilla-pdf library: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

2º With the pdfObject library: http://pdfobject.com/instructions.php

Both libraries are very complete to work with the browser but the mobile devices are other mistake...